# Can't get in_array to work with associative array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble trying to show that certain numbers (product numbers) exist in an associative array. When I try this code, I always get "false".

```
<?php

$products = array(
    '1000' => array('name' => 'Gibson Les Paul Studio',
                    'price' => 1099.99),
    '1001' => array('name' => 'Fender American Standard Stratocaster',
                    'price' => 1149.99),
    '1002' => array('name' => 'Jackson SL1 USA Soloist',
                    'price' => 2999.99)
);

if (in_array('1001', $products)) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
?>
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're looking for [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/array_key_exists), not `in_array()`, since you are searching for a specific key, not searching the values:

```
if( array_key_exists('1001', $products))
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! I am pretty new to all the built-in php functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) here (*checks if a value exists in an array*).

Try [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) (*checks if the given key or index exists in the array*).

```
if (array_key_exists('1001', $products)) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

You can even check for key existance with [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me! That helps me out a lot.